# Center image if other image is not visible

Tags: html, css, center, visible

I'm trying to make simple UI in html.

If one div is not visible, other should be centered to other div, it doesn't happend.
[image]

if all is showned

if 2 of divs are not visible

[image]

my css and html:

```
.playerStats{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hud {
    width: 300px;
    left: -15px;
    /* potrzebne */
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}



.stat {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-height: fit-content;
    max-width: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: rgb(20, 20, 20, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: visibility 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}


.hud .stat img {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: visibility 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.hud .stat .bg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px 15px rgb(115, 0, 230);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: visibility 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

<body>
    <div class="playerStats">
        <div class="hud">
            <div class="stat" id="hp-stat">
                <div class="bg" id="hp" style="background-color: rgb(115, 0, 230)"></div>
                <img src="res/hp.png">
            </div>
            <div class="stat" id="panc-stat">
                <div class="bg" id="panc" style="background-color: rgb(115, 0, 230)"></div>
                <img src="res/panc.png">
            </div>
            <div class="stat" id="pluca-stat">
                <div class="bg" id="pluca" style="background-color: rgb(115, 0, 230)"></div>
                <img src="res/pluca.png">
            </div>
            <div class="stat" id="glos-stat">
                <div class="bg" id="glos" style="background-color: rgb(115, 0, 230)"></div>
                <img src="res/glossredni.png">
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried do something with overflow, but nothing works for me.
Changing position from relative to other, makes weird things.

as you can see, it doesn't center.
idk much of centering stuff in css, so i'm writing it here xD

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to happen. Are you 'removing' one of the items by making its opacity 0? Also, but maybe nothing to do with the problem in your question, why do you have three transition settings (in several places)? The first two will be overriden by the third.

Comment: I'm changing visiblity of div (document.getElementById('panc-stat').style.visibility = 'hidden';)

Comment: and also I fixed transitions ;p

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your markup or styling; when setting `visibility: none`, your element isn't removed from the normal document flow. The element is still there, just invisible. Try `display: none` instead.